# How to change height of elements with same class and diffrent sizes when user clicks on them

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a sidebar that has 3 boxes and every box has its own height.
I want change it's height when user clicks on it's child element.
My solution was saving original height in a global variable.
But i see after changing height the old height will be lost.
how i can store old height of each element ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let`s say this is your HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="inner">click me</div>
</div>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="inner">click me</div>
</div>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="inner">click me</div>
</div>
```

This can be your jQuery:

```
storeHeights = [];
oldHeights = [];
$('.inner').click(function(){
    oldHeights[$parent.index()] = storeHeights[$parent.index()];
    var $parent = $(this).parent();

    // do whatever you want here to set heights or anything    
    // ...
    // ...

    storeHeights[$parent.index()] = $parent.height();
});
```

Comment: you dont need to store the new height, the object has it already

Comment: i used index() of elements but now on second opening and closing boxes their height becomes double ! i think it is because of that i have a second sidebar behind the first one. is there another attribute to use ? also my elements has no id they all have a same class name only. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this

```
<script>
var arrOldHeight = new Array();
var strActive;
function doHeight(o){
    if(strActive != o.id){
        strActive = o.id;
        arrOldHeight[o.id] = o.offsetHeight;

        //how ever you are handling your new height goes here
        o.style.height = "50px";
    }
}
</script>

<body>
<div id="blah_00" style="position:absolute; top:50px; left:200px; height:90px; border:1px solid #000000;" onclick="doHeight(this);">helloWorld</div>
<div id="blah_01" style="position:absolute; top:100px; left:200px; height:90px; border:1px solid #000000;" onclick="doHeight(this);">helloJavascript</div>
</body>
```

Comment: thank you. i have problem in changing element height in second or more clicks too , i want prevent user from making too much clicks. for that i added a class into elements and i remove that class when element height is changed and add that again into the element after animation complete. is it a good idea ?

Comment: that is a second question but guess I will update answer for what I think you are asking

Answer (score -2):

You can append another element in each element with `display:none;` and store its height in that element.
And after that get the text from that element and set it as the parent height.
NOTE : you need to make sure the appended element is not empty (use if).

Comment: This is a really silly idea. You don`t need to create extra elements for this.

Comment: hmmm.. so pls give me better answer , i really dont know what should i do for that. and i thinked maybe asking here helps me to find better way